# Why is this G-AIRMET's valid time earlier than its issued time?

Tags: weather

[image: G-AIRMET. Why valid time after issued time?]

For this G-AIRMET map, why is the valid time earlier than the time it was issued?

Comment: These are created manually by a weather forecaster using data from a specific point in time, and most likely there was some kind of delay in issuing the chart so they came out late.

Comment: Sounds more like an answer than a comment, @Lnafziger. Make it so, Number One!  :)

Comment: Might be a duplicate. This answer seems to (maybe indirectly) address this: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/22893/11953  "From this table you can see that the 6-hour forecasts are usable from the time they are issued until 3 hours after the valid time. The 12 hour forecasts are usable from -3 to +6 hours of the valid time and 24 hour forecasts are usable from -6 to +6 hours of the valid time."

Comment: But then again it might be talking about something completely different - I'm no expert :)

Comment: @freeman That's what I think, and if I was more confident I would, lol.